# ASPOSE PDF NET HorizontalAlignment -- missing justify enumeration value

Tags: pdf-generation, aspose

When i try to set the Aspose.Pdf.HorizontalAlignment value on textstate, the Justify value is missing. I can only see Center,Left,Right and None.
Is there a version issue ? i'm using v8.1.0.0 (2013.06.03).
Thx

Answer (score 0):

The Justify value is present in HorizontalAlignment enumeration when using latest release of [Aspose.Pdf for .NET 11.3.0](http://www.aspose.com/community/files/51/.net-components/aspose.pdf-for-.net/entry687784.aspx). Please see attached image.

My name is Nayyer and I am developer evangelist at Aspose.

[image]

Comment: Thank you  for your answer. Il will then have to move to the latest version.